# JAVA Exception in thread main java.util.no such element

Tags: java, exception

I encountered an error when executing my program.

I execute my program and fed data in an input file.

Contents of the input file

```java
LIMIT
2
ADD 30 60
MUL -60 60
```

I got an exception error as follows.

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
        at Test.doLimit(Test.java:41)
        at Test.checkResult(Test.java:24)
        at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

I googled and I believed that String input = sc.next(); inside the for loop should be causing the error.
May I know how to resolve this error?

My code is as attached below.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    checkResult(input);
}


public static void checkResult(String input)
{
    if(input.equals("LIMIT"))
    {
        //do stuff
        doLimit();
    }
    else if(input.equals("SENT"))
    {
        //do stuff

    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff

    }
}
public static void doLimit()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfInput = sc.nextInt();
    int x,y;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfInput; i++)
    {
        String input = sc.next();
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();

        if(input.equals("ADD"))
        {
            //add

        }
        else if(input.equals("SUB"))
        {
            //sub

        }
        else
        {
            //multiple

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your test input.

Comment: What is the code in line 41?

Comment: What diagnostic steps have you performed? Have you stepped through this in a debugger? What value of `numOfInput` did you get? Did it manage to read the first two values?

Comment: I provided the test input above.
LIMIT
2
ADD 30 60
MUL -60 60

Comment: The code at line 41 is int numOfInput = sc.nextInt();

Comment: Try google using message as a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if there is more input. You can see in the stack trace that `nextInt` is involved and if you look at the SDK you would see that this exception is thrown when

> input is exausted.

anyway you problem is here :

```
int numOfInput = sc.nextInt();
```

so make sure you have valid input before asking for it :

```
if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the data through the input file, you have to provide that `file` in the `Scanner()` constructor.

What you have currently done is provided `System.in`.

**EDIT :**

Also, you have to open the Scanner on the file just once and use it throughout. In this case,

1) You are opening the scanner and reading the first line.

2) Then in the doLimit function, you again open the scanner and read the first line of the input file which is not an integer.

Hence, the error.

Answer (score 0):

The default delimiter of the scanner is the whitespace. However, you plan to use as input for the first 2 lines the new line as delimiter and then either whitespace and new line, as it comes first. Maybe that is the problem. Try writing everything on one line, whitespace separated.